# Type 'NSObject' has no member 'copy'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I just updated to Xcode 8 and now I'm getting the error in my project

**Type 'NSObject' has no member 'copy'.**

Before upgrading Xcode I was not getting this error.

**Note:** I'm still using Swift 2.3. I subclassed UILabel so that I could allow a user to copy text from a label on a long press. Below is my code. The error occurs on the line:

```
if action == #selector(NSObject.copy(_:))
```

Here is the full code:

```
class MCCopyableLabel: UILabel {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    sharedInit()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    sharedInit()
  }

  func sharedInit() {
    userInteractionEnabled = true
    addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MCCopyableLabel.showMenu(_:))))
  }

  func showMenu(sender: AnyObject?) {
    becomeFirstResponder()
    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    if !menu.menuVisible {
      menu.setTargetRect(bounds, inView: self)
      menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }
  }

  override func copy(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let board = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    board.string = text
    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    menu.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
  }

  override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(NSObject.copy(_:)) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: It should probably be `UIResponder.copy(_:)`, or just `copy(_:)`

Comment: @dan Thanks that fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error **Type 'NSObject' has no member 'paste'** after upgrading from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3, I was able to resolve it in the same way as Dan's comment above.

Swift 2

```
#selector(NSObject.paste(_:))
```

Swift 3

```
#selector(paste(_:))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `copy` method does not take a parameter, so you may need to write it as:

```
#selector(NSObject.copy)
```

The notation `#selector(NSObject.copy(_:))` works for a method with one parameter having no label.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dense but doesn't my copy method have one parameter sender? Also, the solution dan added fixed the issue.

Comment: @chickenparm, sorry, I have been missing the context and was just seeing `NSObject` something. The `copy(_:)` you are searching for (which is clearly noted in dan's answer) is another `copy`. I should have noticed it with a little more careful glance at your post. Please keep this answer in mind for future use cases...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I fixed it with:

```
#selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
#selector(UILabel.copy(_:))
```

Comment: This worked. dan's solution he added as a comment also worked. Thanks!